# what is dead code ?

Tags: java, android, dead-code

Here is my code, Eclipse is saying `i++` is dead code... why??

```
for(int i=0;i<packages.size();i++)
        {
            PInfo pinfo = new PInfo();
            pinfo = packages.get(i);
            if(pinfo.pname.contains("com.imdb.mobile"));
            {
            packagesModified.add(pinfo);
            break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of the `;` here:

```
if(pinfo.pname.contains("com.imdb.mobile"));
// ----------------------------------------^
```

The `;` gives the `if` an empty body, and so the block following it *isn't* connected to the `if`, and so your `break;` always happens and the `i++` in the `for` is never reached.

You don't normally put `;` after control statements like `for`, `while`, `if` and such (there are *some* edge cases where all the logic is in the structure, but usually you need a body block or statement attached to them).

---

Unrelated, but there's no reason for the `new PInfo()` here:

```
PInfo pinfo = new PInfo();
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Unnecessary, since you're about to assign
pinfo = packages.get(i);
```